# Secant method, negative answers

Tags: fortran, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to write a program to solve for pipe diameter for a pump system I've designed. I've done this on paper and in excel and understand the mechanics of the equations. I would appreciate any guidance.

At this point I am compiling but getting negative answers on the first iteration, my guess now is that it has to do with my initial guesses, the variables being passed to the function, or the secant calculation code itself. The three checks for phead, pump, and hf are correct.

```
MODULE Sec
CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE Secant(fx,xold,xnew,xolder)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,PARAMETER::DP=selected_real_kind(15)
REAL(DP), PARAMETER:: gamma=62.4
REAL(DP)::z,phead,hf,L,Q,mu,rho,rough,eff,pump,nu,ppow,fric,pres,xnew,xold,xolder,D
INTEGER::I,maxit

INTERFACE
FUNCTION fx(D,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)
Omitted
END FUNCTION
END INTERFACE

Q=0.0353196
Pres=-3600.0
z=-10.0
L=50.0
mu=0.0000273 
rho=1.940
nu=0.5
rough=0.000005
ppow=412.50
xold=1.0
xolder=0.5

phead = (pres/gamma)
WRITE(*,*) phead

pump = (nu*ppow)/(gamma*Q)
WRITE(*,*)pump

hf = phead + z + pump
WRITE(*,*)hf

maxit=20
I = 1

DO
xnew=xold-fx(xold,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)*((xolder-xold)/(fx(xolder,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)-fx(xold,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)))

xolder = xold
xold = xnew
I=I+1
WRITE(*,*) "Diameter = ", xnew
IF (ABS(fx(xnew,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)) <= 0.05) THEN
EXIT
END IF

IF (I >= maxit) THEN
EXIT
END IF 
END DO

END SUBROUTINE Secant
END MODULE Sec

PROGRAM Pipes
USE Sec
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,PARAMETER::DP=selected_real_kind(15)
REAL(DP)::xold,xolder,xnew

INTERFACE
FUNCTION f(D,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)
Omitted
END INTERFACE

CALL Secant(f,xold,xnew,xolder)

END PROGRAM Pipes

FUNCTION f(D,L,Q,hf,rho,mu,rough)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER,PARAMETER::DP=selected_real_kind(15)
REAL(DP), PARAMETER::pi=3.14159265, g=9.81
REAL(DP), INTENT(IN)::L,Q,rough,rho,mu,hf,D
REAL(DP)::f

f=(1/(hf/((L/D)*((4*Q)/pi*D))))+2.0*log((rough/(3.7*D))+(2.51/(((rho*((4*Q)/pi*D))/mu)*(hf/((L/D)*((4*Q)/pi*D))))))
END FUNCTION
```

Comment: @ja72 It is, I edited the previous question since it seemed way too specific and convoluted to help anybody and I was advised to make a new topic. I can't seem to delete the old one though

Comment: If there is a problem with the original posting then edit that and not make a new posting. It is likely this one is going to get closed.